# Remove items from array to ensure no duplicate strings

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to be able to pull 100's of strings from a plist and display them in a label within my project. I have managed to get this to work pulling data from two different arrays within my plist and then generating a random string to display.

What i want to do now is ensure that no two strings are displayed twice in one session and also be able to set a counter system up that after 5 goes it displays a message.

I was thinking of doing a simple counter for the display message after x amount of turns however when it comes to not displaying duplicates from the array im a little lost. I need it to only basically remove an item from the array (not the plist every time the user presses the button)

```
- (IBAction)truth:(id)sender {


NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
                  @"test" ofType:@"plist"];

NSDictionary *plistDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSMutableArray *plistArray = plistDict[@"truth"];


NSDictionary *plistDict2 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSMutableArray *plistArray2 = plistDict2[@"dare"];

plistArray = [plistArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:plistArray2];

NSLog(@"%@", plistArray);


int randV = arc4random() % plistArray.count;


self.joke.text = plistArray[randV];

NSLog(@"dictionary: %@, array: %@", plistDict, plistArray);
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is that every time you are getting a message, you are reading the plists again and recreating `plistArray`

The correct way would be to save plistArray into a local variable (a property) and only populate it the first time.

Then, if you want to remove an item, you call `[plistArray removeObjectAtIndex: randV];

Edit: code

```
// In .h file 
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray * plistArray;


- (IBAction)truth:(id)sender {

if (!self.plistArray) {
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
                  @"test" ofType:@"plist"];

NSDictionary *plistDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSArray * plistArray1 = plistDict[@"truth"];


NSDictionary *plistDict2 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSArray *plistArray2 = plistDict2[@"dare"];

self.plistArray = [[plistArray1 arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:plistArray2] mutableCopy];
}

NSLog(@"%@", plistArray);


int randV = arc4random() % self.plistArray.count;


self.joke.text = self.plistArray[randV];
[self.plistArray removeObjectAtIndex:randV];
NSLog(@"dictionary: %@, array: %@", plistDict, self.plistArray);
}
```

@property

Comment: cant seem to get this to work its displaying plistarray as nil

Comment: It skips the if (!self.plistArray) and goes straign to int randv=arcrandom and thus meaning the plistarray is nil

Comment: have you declared it as a property? if its nil, then it should defintiely go into the if statement. Let me update the code and you can try again

Comment: Ok I updated the function, please try the updated one. Make sure you declare the property plistArray

Comment: I have copied and pasted your code removed the plistdict as this wasnt declared and still returns as nill

Comment: Ok it was me i had a typo sorry to make you scratch your head! Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create an `NSMutableSet` from `plistArray` and each time you retrieve one remove it from the set. Presto!

**EDIT: Add code**

```
NSMutableSet *jokes = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithArray:plistArray];
NSString *joke = [jokes anyObject];
[jokes removeObject:joke];
```

*Disclaimer:* As the documentation says, `anyObject` is not guaranteed to be random. I believe you can work something out for yourself here. E.g.

```
NSString *joke = [[jokes allObjects] objectAtIndex:arc4random() % [jokes count]];
```

Comment: It still shows same items and array isnt getting any smaller

Answer (score 0):

```
[plistArray removeObjectAtIndex: randV];
```

Comment: Cant get this to work

Comment: What error do you receive?